# How to disable body from scrolling when menu is open

Tags: javascript, html, css

How to disable body from scrolling when menu is open? I'v tried using the code below but have had no success.

```
function openNav() { 
    document.getElementsByTagName("body").style.overlay = "hidden"; document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.height = "50%"; }

function closeNav() { 
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.height = "0"; 
}
```

Comment: can you also add the html portion of the code?

Comment: There is no CSS property named `overlay`.

Answer (score 2):

```
document.getElementsByTagName("body").classList.add('hidden');

body.hidden {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding this to the menu will stop the body behind from scrolling.

```
body.menu-open {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

[Doc's on overflow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow)